# Modifying a generator of random numbers from a trapezoidal distribution to include growth and decay rates

Tags: c#, random, distribution

I've written a C# random number generator based on page 11 of this paper: http://pubs.usgs.gov/tm/04/c03/tm4-C3_final_508_files/tm4-C3_apdx1_v030813.pdf

It works fine but I would like to modify it, if possible, to include decay and growth rates as specified in the beginning of this paper: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/trapezoid/vignettes/trapezoid.pdf

Alas, I'm not qualified enough in math to achieve this feat. I would appreciate any help. Here is my code:

```
    class tTrapezoidal
{
public double a, b, c, d, h, Pmax;
private Random pRandom;
public tTrapezoidal(double _a, double _b, double _c, double _d, double _Pmax = 0.999)
{
    pRandom = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
    a = _a;
    b = _b;
    c = _c;
    d = _d;
    h = 2 / ((d - a) + (c - b));
    Pmax = _Pmax;
}

public double GetNext()
{
    double P;
    P = Pmax * (1.0e-6 * (double)pRandom.Next(1000000));
    if (P > 0 && P < h/2*(b-a))
    {
        return a + Math.Sqrt(2*((b-a)/h)) * Math.Sqrt(P);
    }
    else if (P > (h/2) * (b-a) && P < 1 - ((h/2)*(d-c)))
    {
        return ((a+b) / 2) + P / h;
    }
    else
    {
        return d - Math.Sqrt(2 * (d - c) / h) * Math.Sqrt(1 - P);
    }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets start with integrals. BTW, formula in your second paper is wrong, for interval [a...b) it should be \alpha [(x-a)/(b-a)]^{m-1}

```
I1 = Integral_a^b first term = \alpha (b-a)/m
I2 = Integral_b^c second term = (c-b) (1+\alpha)/2
I3 = Integral_c^d third term = (d-c)/n
```

Now first step of the sampling would be

```
- select U(0,1) number
- if it is smaller than I1/(I1+I2+I3) sample from first term
- if no, then substruct I1/(I1+I2+I3) and if it is less than I2/(I1+I2+I3) sample from second term
- otherwise sample from third term
```

Sampling from first term

```
x = a + U(0,1)^(1/m) (b - a)
```

Sampling from third term

```
x = c + U(0,1)^(1/n) (d - c )
```

Sampling from second term to be done in two stages. First, select U(0,1) and
compare against `(1-\alpha)/(1+\alpha)`. If it is lower, sample from linear term, otherwise sample from constant term

From linear term

```
x = b + sqrt(U(0,1)) (c - b)
```

From constant term

```
x = b + U(0,1) (c - b)
```

UPDATE

a bit more common notation